# My var coutParJour dont work

Tags: javascript

```
var nbJour = parseInt(prompt("Combien de jours louez-vous l'auto"));
var distance = parseInt(prompt(" quelle distance aleez-vous parcourir?"));
var coutParJour = 75;
var locAuto = nbJour * coutParJour; 
var coutEssence = distance * 0.07;
var fraisUsure = (distance-(nbJour * 100))
if(fraisUsure > 0){
    fraisUsure * 2;
}else{
    fraisUsure == 0;
}
var coutTotal = locAuto + coutEssence + fraisUsure;
if(nbJour < 6 ){
     coutParJour = 75.00;
    alert(coutTotal +"$" );
}else if(nbJour >= 6 && nbJour <=10){
    var coutParJour = 60.00;
    alert(coutTotal + "$");
}else if(nbJour > 10){ 
    var coutParJour = 55.00;
    alert(coutTotal + "$");
}
```

My `var coutParJour` does not work. What's the problem? It seems it doesn't take the local variable.

Comment: Avoid using var coutParJour  inside else if conditions. You have declared it already.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify what _does not work_ and what your desired output/behaviour is. We cannot guess that from your code. You can [edit] your question with the [edit] link on the bottom left of the question. It's also good to find a more general title that also sounds like a question. You can check [ask] for more details. :)

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, statements are executed in the order that they are written. Simply assigning a value to `coutParJour` will not cause the preceding lines with calculations based on that variable to re-execute. I think what you want is something like this:

```
var nbJour = parseInt(prompt("Combien de jours louez-vous l'auto"));
var distance = parseInt(prompt(" quelle distance aleez-vous parcourir?"));

var coutParJour = 75;
if(nbJour < 6 ){
    coutParJour = 75.00;
else if(nbJour >= 6 && nbJour <=10){
    coutParJour = 60.00;
}else if(nbJour > 10){ 
    coutParJour = 55.00;
}   
var locAuto = nbJour * coutParJour; 
var coutEssence = distance * 0.07;
var fraisUsure = (distance-(nbJour * 100))
if(fraisUsure > 0){
    fraisUsure * 2;
}else{
    fraisUsure == 0;
}
var coutTotal = locAuto + coutEssence + fraisUsure;
alert(coutTotal + "$");
```